# Trying to print cluster names and labels. Getting some overlapping results

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am print out clusters of categorical codes and labels.  I am fitting a dataframe that looks like this.

```
market_cat  local_market_cat    city_cat    state_cat   days_between_Complete
2           0                   30          8           9
2           0                   30          8           1
2           0                   28          8           284
2           0                   30          8           304
2           0                   14          8           334
```

```
y = fuss_2019['days_between_Complete']
X = fuss_2019[['market_cat',
               'local_market_cat',
               'city_cat',
               'state_cat']]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.concat([X, y], axis=1)

from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Now, I am trying to join two dataframes on the index, then print out the city names and cluster IDs.

```
df1=df
df2=fuss_2019
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(df)

details = [(name, cluster) for name, cluster in zip(merged['city'],kmeans.labels_)]
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```

Here are my results:

```
('Indianapolis', 0)
('Indianapolis', 0)
('Greenwood', 1)
('Indianapolis', 1)
etc.,
('New York', 0)
('Yonkers', 2)
('New York', 0)
('New York', 2)
etc.,
```

What would why would Indianapolis be in both cluster 0 and 1? Also, why would New York be in cluster 0 and 2?  Did I miss something here, or can the same city end up in two different clusters?  KMeans is non-overlapping, right.

Comment: Actually, as I look at this closer now, I think it's because I'm fitting the model on all these features: 'days_between_Complete', 'market_cat', 'local_market_cat',                'city_cat', and 'state_cat'.  It's fitting on all features, not just one or two features.  I suppose that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a great resource.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster

df = pd.read_csv ('C:\\your_path_here\\cities.csv')
print(df)

cities = df

# K-means clustering based on longitude-latitude
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(10)
kmeans.fit(cities[['longitude', 'latitude']])
labels = kmeans.labels_
plt.scatter(cities['longitude'], cities['latitude'], c=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Try different values for K
# Now with centroids
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(5)
kmeans.fit(cities[['longitude', 'latitude']])
labels = kmeans.labels_
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(cities['longitude'], cities['latitude'], c=labels)
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], marker='x', c='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# K-means clustering based on temperature
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(3)
kmeans.fit(cities[['temperature']])
labels = kmeans.labels_
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(cities['longitude'], cities['latitude'], c=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
details = [(name, cluster) for name, cluster in zip(df['city'],kmeans.labels_)]
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```

Results:

```
('Aalborg', 0)
('Aberdeen', 1)
('Abisko', 0)
('Adana', 2)
('Albacete', 2)
('Algeciras', 2)
('Amiens', 1)
('Amsterdam', 1)
('Ancona', 2)
('Andorra', 1)
('Angers', 1)
('Ankara', 1)
```

https://www.instabase.com/widom/ML-Python/fs/Instabase%20Drive/Cities.csv